# php mail invalid HELO name

Tags: php, wamp

i am trying to use localhost to send mail. however, i am getting this error when sending:

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1). i have smtp settings correct in php.ini and am just confused as to what this means. thanks

Comment: Your problem is related to your MTA (Mail Transport Agent). Please specify what MTA are you using (postfix, exim?), post configuration and consider retagging, as this is a MTA issue.

Comment: as you taged as wamp, try to add this two settings with the proper values to your php.ini: auth_username, auth_password. this error is sometimes seen when you are not allowed to send via an SMTP but could if you SMTP Auth yourself. (mail login credentials)

Comment: @lukas [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/ 
SMTP = mail.mydomain.org
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = admin@mydomain.org
auth_password = 111111

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
admin@mydomain.org i have removed domain and substituted with domain. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two primary reasons for this.

1. The first has to do with the email client configuration (google INVALID HELO OUTLOOK).
2. The other reason  is an improperly configured SMTP server where the server sends out emails with only the server name and not a fully qualified name (e.g., emailserver vs emailserver.mydomain.com).

You should contact your hosting company and give them as much detail as you can. They should be able to help.

If you are using cPanel, you can disable HELO checking. See the user guide. The trade off is you will receive more spam...

Comment: thanks for reply. is it thus possible to send mail from localhost whilst in development stage?

Comment: excellent chris. worked a treat. because i am not logged in how do i give answer to you? thanks

Comment: You have to be logged in to post, so I think you are logged in. Please just click the tick next to my answer and the up arrow next to the 0! Thanks :)

Comment: actualy chris you do not have to be logged in. that is only if you have openid. i just supplied name and email to post question. the only answer that i can see is next to your original post and not the answer in your latest comment that gave the corrct solution. do i just tick that one? thanks

Comment: yeah you just click the one next to the main answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with postfix in Ubuntu. It turned out that I'd not set 'myhostname' in the postfix configuration file.

The problem disappeared when I configured 'myhostname' in the following file:

/etc/postfix/main.cf